# Calculate the probability $P(S^2_{n-1}<s^2_{n-1})$ by Monte-Carlo simulation of the population distribution

Tags: self-study, python, monte-carlo, probabilistic-programming

i am struggling with the following problem, i have posted my attempt below, i am apparently supposed to get an answer of 0.632 with a random seed of 25 however i get a 1 as the answer. Please help i cant see where i am going wrong.

Thanks.

Calculate the probability $P(S^2_{n-1}<s^2_{n-1})$ by Monte-Carlo simulation of the population distribution assuming that:

$$
    \frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma} \sim T_{5} \quad \text{ie. a students-t distribution with 5 degrees of freedom}
$$

and where $s^2_{n-1}=14.41$. Simulate 1000 samples of 20 observations.

```
# fix random generator seed
np.random.seed(25)

# variable for number of simulation and sample size and variance list for each sample
sample_size = 1000
sample_var = np.float64(14.41)
n = 20
var_list = []

# Simulate 1000 samples of 20 observations from student's t-distribution with 5 degrees of freedom
random_samples = np.random.standard_t(df=5,size=(sample_size,n))

# Obtain variance of each random sample to make sampling distribution
for r_sample in random_samples:
    var = np.var(r_sample,ddof=1)
    var_list.append(var)

# count where simulated variance is less  than sample variance, this will give us the probability
mc_prob = np.sum(var_list < sample_var)/sample_size    
print('mc_prob =',mc_prob)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the code stands in simulating a standard Student's variate rather than a location-scale Student's variate. In the code,

```
random_samples = np.random.standard_t(df=5,size=(sample_size,n))
```

should be

```
random_samples = sigma*np.random.standard_t(df=5,size=(sample_size,n))+mu
```