# If $X_1, ..., X_n$ come from $\exp(5)$ using CLT, Calculate the probability $P(Z<z)$

Tags: self-study, python, central-limit-theorem, computational-statistics

Please advise if the approach i am taking below is correct, I don't see how else to go about solving this problem.

`import numpy as np

# generate data
np.random.seed(0)
dataset = np.random.exponential(scale =1/5, size = (30,1))
n = len(dataset)

# for an exponential distribution E[x] = 1/lambda = mean and var = 1/lambda**2
expected_value = 1/(1/5) # reciprocal of lambda we are given as 5 in this instance
standard_deviation = np.sqrt(1/(1/5)**2)

# Z = (X_bar - E[X_bar])/sd(X_bar) using CLT.
Z = ((dataset.mean() - expected_value)/standard_deviation)*np.sqrt(n)

# Calculate z_score for the dataset z_score = (sample - sample_mean)/sample_deviation
z_scores  = (dataset - dataset.mean())/(dataset.std())

# Check dataset where z_score > Z random variable
condition = z_scores > Z

# Probability is number of desired outcome condition/ total outcomes
prob = len(dataset[condition])/len(dataset)
print(prob)`

Comment: Your $Z$ does not appear to consider the sample size, $n$.

Comment: @Dave thanks i will add it, i was just not sure if i needed to divide by $\sqrt(n)$ for $Z$ if i am using the population parameter to obtain the standard deviation. I however see that i need to add it when calculating the z_scores.

Comment: I do not follow what you say about the population parameter (do you mean $n$ vs $n-1$?), but the central limit theorem concerns $Z=\sqrt{n}\dfrac{\bar{X}_n-\mu} {\sigma}$.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, i have edited the calculation for $Z$ above, any other comments with regards to the approach?

Comment: It is impossible to tell what the question really is, because it appears to be a combination of coding problems and conceptual ones--but everything is expressed in code only.  Could you back up a little and explain, in words, what your problem is?

Comment: @whuber i was basically asked to draw 30 samples from  the $exp(5)$ distribution and having obtained that compute $P(Z<z)$ where $Z=\sqrt{n}\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu} {\sigma}$ does this help?. That is the extent to which i understand the problem.

Comment: This becomes more mysterious.  What are $\mu$ and $\sigma$?  Would they be the true mean and SD or the sample mean and SD?  And how is it proposed that you use a *sample* to calculate a property of a distribution?

Comment: @whuber that is precisely why i asked the question here as im not sure what to make of the parameters. I found that given the $\lambda$ for the exponential distribution one can determine $\mu$ and  $\sigma$ i.e. true mean and SD.  And then perhaphs do something with the $z score$ of the sample. i'd hoped it would make sense to someone who is more seasoned in the topic, im fairly new to all this. Unfortunately i couldnt get more information out of the lecturer besides what i have already given.

Comment: On closer inspection perhaps this is similar to my previous question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532136/calculate-the-probability-ps2-n-1s2-n-1-by-monte-carlo-simulation-of/532183#532183 where i also needed to determine the  probability between a distribution and sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment:**

Suppose $X_i$ are IID $\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate}=\lambda=1/3)\equiv
\mathsf{Exp}(\mu = 3)$ and $Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.$ Then $Z$ is not well modeled by a normal distribution unless $n$ is in the hundreds. This is because of the skewness of the exponential distribution and the consequent slowness of the convergence of the CLT.

Illustrations by simulation in R for $\mu = 3$ and for $n=36, n=400.$

```
set.seed(2021)
a.36 = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(36, 1/3)))
z.36 = (a.36-3)/(3/sqrt(36))
summary(z.36);  sd(z.36)

     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-3.234041 -0.701673 -0.057333 -0.000163  0.643720  5.548458 
[1] 1.00098  # SD 

set.seed(620)
a.400 = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(400, 1/3)))
z.400 = (a.400-3)/(3/sqrt(400))
summary(z.400);  sd(z.400)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-4.092648 -0.686992 -0.019076 -0.001976  0.663559  4.777723 
[1] 0.9988278
```

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hdr = "n=36: z-Scores of Exponential Means"
hist(z.36, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
hdr = "n=400: z-Scores of Exponential Means"
hist(z.400, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dnorm(x), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

By contrast, for any $n,$ exponential means are exactly
distributed according to the ratios $\frac{\bar X}{\mu} \sim 
\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=n, \mathrm{rate}=n).$ This is
easy to show, using moment generating functions. (Appropriate gamma density functions are superimposed on histograms below.)

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hdr = "n=36: Distn's of Exponential Mean Ratios"
hist(a.36/3, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dgamma(x,36,36), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
hdr = "n=400: Distn's of Exponential Mean Ratios"
hist(a.400/3, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 curve(dgamma(x, 400,400), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

**Answers** for $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda=.2)$ with $E(X_i) = SD(X_i) = 5.$

We have the normal approximation $P(\bar X_n \le 5) = P\left(Z_n = \frac{\bar X_n-5}{5/\sqrt{n}} \le 0\right) \approx 0.5,$ for all $n>1.$

By contrast, we have the values
$P(Z_n \le 0) = P(\bar X_n \le 5) = 
P\left(\frac{\bar X_n}{5} \le \frac 5 5 = 1\right),$
which can be evaluated exactly using the distribution
$\mathsf{Gamma}(n,n)$ for all $n>0.$ Values for $n = 10, 36, 100, 400$ are shown below.

```
pgamma(1, 10, 10)
[1] 0.5420703
pgamma(1, 36, 36)
[1] 0.5221667
pgamma(1, 100, 100)
[1] 0.5132988
pgamma(1, 400, 400)
[1] 0.5066491
```